# Sails.js equivalent of Rails before_save?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sails.js

I've done some rails callbacks before (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

I want to call a function before saving a model (image) that will get the width / height of that image before saving it to the database. Using this function:

```
function getMeta(url){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    s = {w :this.width, h:this.height;}
  };
  img.src = url;
  return s;
}

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    source: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    height: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: getMeta(this.source).h
    },
    width: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: getMeta(this.source).w
    }

  }
};
```

The downsides are, 1) it doesn't work; 2) I call that function twice.

Is there a way to call that function before creating, set 2 local variables, then save it with those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails.js has [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks) which include `beforeUpdate` and `beforeCreate`

Comment: I found these as well. I can't call `Image` from the controller though. Seems as though it is unavailable to the backend.